# Ubuntu Pro on AWS | Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, aws, ubuntu-pro

I created a new EC2 instance with Ubuntu Pro 22.04 image. After 1st access, I updated system packages and Audited/fixed using usg command.

After usg fix command, I rebooted the system and upon 1st access after reboot, the system is having DNS resolution issues. I have checked /etc/resolv.conf, its unchanged.

Errors:
Temporary failure in name resolution
communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out